# apache wildcard ssl on subdomain serves same page for non ssl virtualhosts

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost, wildcard-subdomain

Issue observed: I have configured ng.my-site.com using widlcard ssl cert. When I hit https://www.my-site.com   it loads ng.my-site.com website!

please advise if I missed any concept / configs... Thank you!

### httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.my-site.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@my-site.com

   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite
   ErrorLog logs/my-site-error.log
   CustomLog logs/my-site-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ng.my-site.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@my-site.com

   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ng
   ErrorLog logs/ng-my-site-error.log
   CustomLog logs/ng-my-site-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

### ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost ng.my-site.com:443>
    ServerName ng.my-site.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@my-site.com

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.key 

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ng
ErrorLog logs/ng-my-site-ssl-error.log
CustomLog logs/ng-my-site-ssl-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So what do you expect it to do? There is no configuration for www.my-site.com:443.

Comment: Right no configuration for www.my-site.com:443 - anyone hits should see "no secure site for this url"

Why does apache  pickups  ng.my-site.com and serves pages from this.?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [Name-Based VirtualHosts and SSL](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts):

> ... Apache will allow you to configure name-based SSL virtual hosts, but it will always use the configuration from the first-listed virtual host (on the selected IP address and port) to setup the encryption layer.

Thus, you've setup a virtual host on a specific IP address and port (does not matter if you've given a hostname, IP is taken). This means it will accept connections on this IP address. And, since you've given no other virtual host it will take the configuration of the first. Since you have a wildcard certificate there the browser will not complain.

If you want different configurations for different hosts add the appropriate configurations. If you want to have an error message for all but this specific host add a default host which serves the error.

Comment: Thank you!

What is the best way to avoid - so that if a user requests https which has no virtual host can be redirected to http?

Comment: @ashokr: setup a default virtual host for https and make it redirect the request. Note that the certificate still needs to be valid for the URL the client accesses - but given that you are using a wildcard certificate this should hopefully be the case.

Answer (score 0):

It works! I just had to add in my ssl.conf this will avoid non-ssl sites to get redirected back to HTTP.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ng.my-site.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```